# How do I update Eclipse CVS Client feature in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-luna

We require some bespoke changes to support our eclipse dev environment.

We have modified the plugin:

org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui

...and the feature:

org.eclipse.cvs-feature

...that references this plugin with our version

We then created an update site with this feature.

This approach works with no problems when worked with the plugins/features in Helios.

The same approach does not work in Luna. The error I get when I try and install the update site is:

```
Your original request has been modified.
  "Eclipse CVS Client" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse CVS Client 1.4.101.kirona (org.eclipse.cvs.feature.group 1.4.101.kirona)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers 4.4.1.20140925-1820 (epp.package.standard 4.4.1.20140925-1820)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    CVS Team Provider UI 3.3.601.kirona (org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui 3.3.601.kirona)
    CVS Team Provider UI 3.3.600.v20130514-1224 (org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui 3.3.600.v20130514-1224)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers 4.4.1.20140925-1820 (epp.package.standard 4.4.1.20140925-1820)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.feature.feature.group [4.4.1.20140925-1820]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse CVS Client 1.4.100.v20140925-0400 (org.eclipse.cvs.feature.group 1.4.100.v20140925-0400)
    To: org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui [3.3.600.v20130514-1224]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse CVS Client 1.4.101.kirona (org.eclipse.cvs.feature.group 1.4.101.kirona)
    To: org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui [3.3.601.kirona]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse CVS Client Resources 1.4.100.v20140925-0400 (org.eclipse.cvs.source.feature.group 1.4.100.v20140925-0400)
    To: org.eclipse.cvs.feature.group [1.4.100.v20140925-0400]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EPP Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers Feature 4.4.1.20140925-1820 (org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.feature.feature.group 4.4.1.20140925-1820)
    To: org.eclipse.cvs.source.feature.group 0.0.0
```

As you can see we are basically trying to update the plugin from:

```
    CVS Team Provider UI 3.3.600.v20130514-1224 (org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui 3.3.600.v20130514-1224)
```

to:

```
    CVS Team Provider UI 3.3.601.kirona (org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui 3.3.601.kirona)
```

I do not understand why we cannot update this CVS feature?? It appears the software "Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers" that references this CVS feature is causing a conflict?

Any ideas how we can resolve this issue??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably something has an exact version requirement. Have a look at the 'Why am I getting dependency satisfaction errors when I update my feature?' section of the [p2 FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/FAQ)

Comment: The link you sent me specifies my issue exactly thanks! But what do I do now? It states that "the solution is to relax the product/feature definition to allow a version range on the updated.feature rather than an exact version by complementing the .product file with a carefully-crafted p2.inf file". So do I need to check out the "Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers" product and make changes there and also update that? This is a lot of work after updating one bundle!

Comment: Sorry but I don't know. Updating Eclipse source like this is unusual.